# Symfony2 bundle and Travis-CI

Tags: php, symfony, travis-ci

I add my bundle to travic-ci. But my project fails with message

```
The service "my.form_extension" has a dependency on a non-existent service "validator".
```

I cant understand why this error appear, in composer.json I has

```
"symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/validator": "2.6.*@dev"
```

So validator service exists in `framework-bundle`. Whats I am doing wrong?

P.S. before-script in travis.yml

```
before_script:
  - composer self-update
  - composer install
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validator is [only registered if validation is enabled](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/e18b89c1be2b8e62b6522d34df31bb51aedd88ca/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L717) via the configuration. In your test configuration you need to enable validation under the framework section (just [like in standard edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/7a8a4fb179d7c98f2129ffd37eeb8e20a1bca3d7/app/config/config.yml#L15)):

```
framework:
    validation: ~
```